# How should I clean up hung grandchild processes when an alarm trips in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, kill, alarm, grandchild

I have a parallelized automation script which needs to call many other scripts, some of which hang because they (incorrectly) wait for standard input or wait around for various other things that aren't going to happen. That's not a big deal because I catch those with [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html). The trick is to shut down those hung grandchild processes when the child shuts down. I thought various incantations of `SIGCHLD`, waiting, and process groups could do the trick, but they all block and the grandchildren aren't reaped.

My solution, which works, just doesn't seem like it is the right solution. I'm not especially interested in the Windows solution just yet, but I'll eventually need that too. Mine only works for Unix, which is fine for now.

I wrote a small script that takes the number of simultaneous parallel children to run and the total number of forks:

```
 $ fork_bomb <parallel jobs> <number of forks>

 $ fork_bomb 8 500
```

This will probably hit the per-user process limit within a couple of minutes. Many solutions I've found just tell you to increase the per-user process limit, but I need this to run about 300,000 times, so that isn't going to work. Similarly, suggestions to re-exec and so on to clear the process table aren't what I need. I'd like to actually fix the problem instead of slapping duct tape over it.

I crawl the process table looking for the child processes and shut down the hung processes individually in the `SIGALRM` handler, which needs to die because the rest of real code has no hope of success after that. The kludgey crawl through the process table doesn't bother me from a performance perspective, but I wouldn't mind not doing it:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Proc::ProcessTable;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new( $ARGV[0] );

my $alarm_sub = sub {
        kill 9,
            map  { $_->{pid} }
            grep { $_->{ppid} == $$ }
            @{ Proc::ProcessTable->new->table }; 

        die "Alarm rang for $$!\n";
        };

foreach ( 0 .. $ARGV[1] ) 
    {
    print ".";
    print "\n" unless $count++ % 50;

    my $pid = $pm->start and next; 

    local $SIG{ALRM} = $alarm_sub;

    eval {
        alarm( 2 );
        system "$^X -le '<STDIN>'"; # this will hang
        alarm( 0 );
        };

    $pm->finish;
    }
```

If you want to run out of processes, take out the [kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html).

I thought that setting a process group would work so I could kill everything together, but that blocks:

```
my $alarm_sub = sub {
        kill 9, -$$;    # blocks here
        die "Alarm rang for $$!\n";
        };

foreach ( 0 .. $ARGV[1] ) 
    {
    print ".";
    print "\n" unless $count++ % 50;

    my $pid = $pm->start and next; 
    setpgrp(0, 0);

    local $SIG{ALRM} = $alarm_sub;

    eval {
        alarm( 2 );
        system "$^X -le '<STDIN>'"; # this will hang
        alarm( 0 );
        };

    $pm->finish;
    }
```

The same thing with [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html)'s `setsid` didn't work either, and I think that actually broke things in a different way since I'm not really daemonizing this.

Curiously, [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parallel-ForkManager)'s `run_on_finish` happens too late for the same clean-up code: the grandchildren are apparently already disassociated from the child processes at that point.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't close STDIN in the children?

Comment: That might be a good idea too. I'll have to think about that, although I was considering handling some of the bad cases with something like Expect to get them to do that they need to do.

Comment: See long answer below.  But basically, I think you need more control over the situation than Parallel::ForkManager lets you have, which means you have to roll your own.

Comment: Huh, now that I have fixed most of the problems, the great grandchild processes are a problem too. Those are parts per thousand, but now that I'm running tens of thousands of jobs in one run they are starting to acculumate.

Comment: Can you really get `system "perl -le '<STDIN>'"` to time out? I see that it immediately suspends the process that spawned it, and the SIGALRM doesn't go out until the process wakes up.

Comment: The alarm works fine for me. The calling process continues, shuts down, and leaves the dissociated grandchild. That's how it can fill up the process table.

Answer (score 8):

I've read the question a few times, and I think I sort of get what you
are trying to do.  You have a control script.  This script spawns
children to do some stuff, and these children spawn the grandchildren
to actually do the work.  The problem is that the grandchildren can be
too slow (waiting for STDIN, or whatever), and you want to kill them.
Furthermore, if there is one slow grandchild, you want the entire
child to die (killing the other grandchildren, if possible).

So, I tried implementing this two ways.  The first was to make the
parent spawn a child in a new UNIX session, set a timer for a few
seconds, and kill the entire child session when the timer went off.
This made the parent responsible for both the child and the
grandchildren.  It also didn't work right.

The next strategy was to make the parent spawn the child, and then
make the child responsible for managing the grandchildren.  It would
set a timer for each grandchild, and kill it if the process hadn't
exited by expiration time.  This works great, so here is the code.

We'll use EV to manage the children and timers, and AnyEvent for the
API.  (You can try another AnyEvent event loop, like Event or POE.
But I know that EV correctly handles the condition where a child exits
before you tell the loop to monitor it, which eliminates annoying race
conditions that other loops are vulnerable to.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';

use AnyEvent;
use EV; # you need EV for the best child-handling abilities
```

We need to keep track of the child watchers:

```
# active child watchers
my %children;
```

Then we need to write a function to start the children.  The things
the parent spawns are called children, and the things the children
spawn are called jobs.

```
sub start_child($$@) {
    my ($on_success, $on_error, @jobs) = @_;
```

The arguments are a callback to be called when the child completes
successfully (meaning its jobs were also a success), a callback when
the child did not complete successfully, and then a list of coderef
jobs to run.

In this function, we need to fork.  In the parent, we setup a child
watcher to monitor the child:

```
    if(my $pid = fork){ # parent
        # monitor the child process, inform our callback of error or success
        say "$$: Starting child process $pid";
        $children{$pid} = AnyEvent->child( pid => $pid, cb => sub {
            my ($pid, $status) = @_;
            delete $children{$pid};

            say "$$: Child $pid exited with status $status";
            if($status == 0){
                $on_success->($pid);
            }
            else {
                $on_error->($pid);
            }
        });
    }
```

In the child, we actually run the jobs.  This involves a little bit of
setup, though.

First, we forget the parent's child watchers, because it doesn't make
sense for the child to be informed of its siblings exiting.  (Fork is
fun, because you inherit all of the parent's state, even when that
makes no sense at all.)

```
    else { # child
        # kill the inherited child watchers
        %children = ();
        my %timers;
```

We also need to know when all the jobs are done, and whether or not
they were all a success.  We use a counting conditional variable to
determine when everything has exited.  We increment on startup, and
decrement on exit, and when the count is 0, we know everything's done.

I also keep a boolean around to indicate error state.  If a process
exits with a non-zero status, error goes to 1.  Otherwise, it stays 0.
You might want to keep more state than this :)

```
        # then start the kids
        my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;
        my $error = 0;

        $done->begin;
```

(We also start the count at 1 so that if there are 0 jobs, our process
still exits.)

Now we need to fork for each job, and run the job.  In the parent, we
do a few things.  We increment the condvar.  We set a timer to kill
the child if it's too slow.  And we setup a child watcher, so we can
be informed of the job's exit status.

```
    for my $job (@jobs) {
            if(my $pid = fork){
                say "[c] $$: starting job $job in $pid";
                $done->begin;

                # this is the timer that will kill the slow children
                $timers{$pid} = AnyEvent->timer( after => 3, interval => 0, cb => sub {
                    delete $timers{$pid};

                    say "[c] $$: Killing $pid: too slow";
                    kill 9, $pid;
                });

                # this monitors the children and cancels the timer if
                # it exits soon enough
                $children{$pid} = AnyEvent->child( pid => $pid, cb => sub {
                    my ($pid, $status) = @_;
                    delete $timers{$pid};
                    delete $children{$pid};

                    say "[c] [j] $$: job $pid exited with status $status";
                    $error ||= ($status != 0);
                    $done->end;
                });
            }
```

Using the timer is a little bit easier than alarm, since it carries
state with it.  Each timer knows which process to kill, and it's easy
to cancel the timer when the process exits successfully -- we just
delete it from the hash.

That's the parent (of the child).  The child (of the child; or the
job) is really simple:

```
            else {
                # run kid
                $job->();
                exit 0; # just in case
            }
```

You could also close stdin here, if you wanted to.

Now, after all the processes have been spawned, we wait for them to
all exit by waiting on the condvar.  The event loop will monior the
children and timers, and do the right thing for us:

```
        } # this is the end of the for @jobs loop
        $done->end;

        # block until all children have exited
        $done->recv;
```

Then, when all the children have exited, we can do whatever cleanup
work we want, like:

```
        if($error){
            say "[c] $$: One of your children died.";
            exit 1;
        }
        else {
            say "[c] $$: All jobs completed successfully.";
            exit 0;
        }
    } # end of "else { # child"
} # end of start_child
```

OK, so that's the child and grandchild/job.  Now we just need to write
the parent, which is a lot easier.

Like the child, we are going to use a counting condvar to wait for our
children.

```
# main program
my $all_done = AnyEvent->condvar;
```

We need some jobs to do.  Here's one that is always successful, and
one that will be successful if you press return, but will fail if you
just let it be killed by the timer:

```
my $good_grandchild = sub {
    exit 0;
};

my $bad_grandchild = sub {
    my $line = <STDIN>;
    exit 0;
};
```

So then we just need to start the child jobs.  If you remember way
back to the top of `start_child`, it takes two callbacks, an error
callback, and a success callback.  We'll set those up; the error
callback will print "not ok" and decrement the condvar, and the
success callback will print "ok" and do the same.  Very simple.

```
my $ok  = sub { $all_done->end; say "$$: $_[0] ok" };
my $nok = sub { $all_done->end; say "$$: $_[0] not ok" };
```

Then we can start a bunch of children with even more grandchildren
jobs:

```
say "starting...";

$all_done->begin for 1..4;
start_child $ok, $nok, ($good_grandchild, $good_grandchild, $good_grandchild);
start_child $ok, $nok, ($good_grandchild, $good_grandchild, $bad_grandchild);
start_child $ok, $nok, ($bad_grandchild, $bad_grandchild, $bad_grandchild);
start_child $ok, $nok, ($good_grandchild, $good_grandchild, $good_grandchild, $good_grandchild);
```

Two of those will timeout, and two will succeed.  If you press enter
while they're running, though, then they might all succeed.

Anyway, once those have started, we just need to wait for them to
finish:

```
$all_done->recv;

say "...done";

exit 0;
```

And that's the program.

One thing that we aren't doing that Parallel::ForkManager does is
"rate limiting" our forks so that only `n` children are running at a
time.  This is pretty easy to manually implement, though:

```
 use Coro;
 use AnyEvent::Subprocess; # better abstraction than manually
                           # forking and making watchers
 use Coro::Semaphore;

 my $job = AnyEvent::Subprocess->new(
    on_completion => sub {}, # replace later
    code          => sub { the child process };
 )

 my $rate_limit = Coro::Semaphore->new(3); # 3 procs at a time

 my @coros = map { async {
     my $guard = $rate_limit->guard;
     $job->clone( on_completion => Coro::rouse_cb )->run($_);
     Coro::rouse_wait;
 }} ({ args => 'for first job' }, { args => 'for second job' }, ... );

 # this waits for all jobs to complete
 my @results = map { $_->join } @coros;
```

The advantage here is that you can do other things while your children
are running -- just spawn more threads with `async` before you do the
blocking join.  You also have a lot more control over the children
with AnyEvent::Subprocess -- you can run the child in a Pty and feed
it stdin (like with Expect), and you can capture its stdin and stdout
and stderr, or you can ignore those things, or whatever.  You get to
decide, not some module author that's trying to make things "simple".

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you can cut-n-paste the code into a script and run it.  Just delete the text.

Answer (score 1):

Brian - it's a bit crude and non-idiomatic, but one approach I've seen taken is this: anytime you fork, you:

1. Give the child process a first "-id" dummy parameter to the program, with a somewhat unique (per PID) value - a good candidate could be up-to-millisecond timestamp + parent's PID.
2. The parent records the child PID and a -id value into a (ideally, persistent) registry along with the desired timeout/kill time.

Then have a watcher process (either the ultimate grandparent or a separate process with the same UID) simply cycle through the registry periodically, and check which processes needing to be killed (as per to-kill-time) are still hanging around (by matching both PID and "-id" parameter value in the registry with the PIDs and command line in process table); and send signal 9 to such process (or be nice and try to kill gently first by trying to send signal 2).

The unique "-id" parameter is obviously intended to prevent killing some innocent process that just happened to re-use a prior process's PID by coincidence, which is probably likely given the scale you mentioned.

The idea of a registry helps with the problem of "already disassociated" grand-children since you no longer depend on the system to keep parent/child association for you.

This is kind of brute force, but since nobody answered yet I figured I'll though my 3 cents worth of an idea your way.

Comment: This is a band-aid, not a solution. I know about the brute force things I can do, but I'm actually trying to get at the real problem without creating all sorts of weird coupling within the program.

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve this same problem in a module [I've been working on](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MOB/Forks-Super-0.31/lib/Forks/Super/Job/Timeout.pm). I'm not completely satisfied with all of my solution(s) either, but what generally works on Unix is to

1. change a child's process group
2. spawn grandchildren as necessary
3. change the child's process group again (say, back to its original value)
4. signal the grandchildren's process group to kill the grandchildren

Something like:

```
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);

sub be_sleepy { sleep 2 ** (5 * rand()) }
$SIGINT = 2;

for (0 .. $ARGV[1]) {
    print ".";
    print "\n" unless ++$count % 50;
    if (fork() == 0) {   
        # a child process
        # $ORIGINAL_PGRP and $NEW_PGRP should be global or package or object level vars
        $ORIGINAL_PGRP = getpgrp(0);
        setpgrp(0, $$);
        $NEW_PGRP = getpgrp(0);

        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
            kill_grandchildren();
            die "$$ timed out\n";
        };

        eval {
            alarm 2;
            while (rand() < 0.5) {
                if (fork() == 0) {
                    be_sleepy();
                }
            }
            be_sleepy();
            alarm 0;
            kill_grandchildren();
        };

        exit 0;
    }
}

sub kill_grandchildren {
    setpgrp(0, $ORIGINAL_PGRP);
    kill -$SIGINT, $NEW_PGRP;   # or  kill $SIGINT, -$NEW_PGRP
}
```

This isn't completely fool proof. The grandchildren might change their process groups or trap signals.

None of this will work on Windows, of course, but let's just say that `TASKKILL /F /T` is your friend.

---

**Update:** This solution doesn't handle (for me, anyway) the case when the child process invokes `system "perl -le '<STDIN>'"`.  For me, this immediately suspends the process, and prevents the SIGALRM from firing and the SIGALRM handler from running. Is closing `STDIN` the only workaround?

Comment: This doesn't work for my particular case either. I have to handle that  <STDIN> case, which is the most common reason for a blocked process in my application. My current thought on that is to open a bi-directional pipe instead and then close the input (child to grandchild) immediately.